# Parallel HTTP requests with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I have an Android application that is currently using `Volley` library to make network requests and show downloaded images with `NetworkImageView`.

I would like to test `Retrofit`'s capabilities and since I need to run lots of requests (thousands) I'm a bit concerned about the parallel execution. `Volley` handles parallel requests with the `RequestQueue` that limits the concurrent running requests to four, while the other requests are enqueued waiting to be executed. In `Retrofit` documentations I haven't found any way to handle the number of concurrent requests and I suspect that such details are left to the developer in this library.

Is this correct? If so, is there any android-oriented implementation/library available? Otherwise, what are the best practices to handle parallel requests?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Retrofit uses an `Executor` for queueing requests.

The default uses `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` which allows for unlimited threads. This fits most use cases since normally you would only ever have one or two requests happening at once.

You can change this behavior, however, by supplying your own when building the `RestAdapter`. Call [`setExecutors`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.Builder.html#setExecutors(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) and pass in an executor that uses a confined thread pool (limited to whatever number you would like). For the second argument, simply pass a new instance of [`MainThreadExecutor`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/android/MainThreadExecutor.html) so that callbacks happen on the main thread.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to handle my threads? If yes, I was using this before migrating to `Volley`, but I had two main problems: 1) I was losing some requests because the queue was full, Volley has an unbounded queue. 2) Some requests were removed from the queue because they were waiting too long.

Comment: Yes. Using an unbounded queue will solve both 1 and 2. There are a few in `java.util.concurrent` to choose from.

Comment: Please provide code example of how to limit to max 5 requests at a time

Comment: ```RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()

                .setEndpoint(SomeEndpoint)

                .setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), null)

                .build();
```


Note the second arg is the callback executor - this will put the callback on the same thread as the client.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.Builder.html#setExecutors-java.util.concurrent.Executor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-

Comment: @JakeWharton So when building the RestAdapter and using `setExecutors`, it will set a specified number of allowed requests to be put into the queue (if needed) correct? How would one be able to handle the concurrency upon receiving the response from the `CallBack`? Does retrofit handle this?

Comment: Can this method be used with the latest Retrofit 2.0 ??

Comment: With **retrofit 2.0**, as in written in this [retrofit github issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1259), OkHttpClient dispatcher has to be used. There is a sample in [this other github issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1936).