# Retrofit thread safety

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rest, retrofit

I wrapped my Retrofit code in a class like below. If it's not clear from the code I'm posting it's interacting with a restful service with OAuth.

Is this OK for thread safety? I mean say the user clicks two places at once and fires off two API calls. Is this code any good? Do I need to keep an internal queue? And if so how should I go about it?

Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255889/672009) answer I'd say, no. But I'm not sure.

```
public class RestClient implements IRestClient {
    private IRestAPI api;

    /**
     *
     * @param accessToken
     */
    public RestClient(final String accessToken)
    {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            }
        };

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
        api = restAdapter.create(IRestAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void getUserProfile(Callback callback) {
        api.getUserProfile(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void getFriendList(Callback callback) {
        api.getFriendList(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(User user, String message, Callback callback) {
        api.sendMessage(user, message, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void createSomething(Some thing, Callback callback) {
        api.createSomething(thing, callback);
    }

    ...
}
```

Suggestions/comments and whatnot is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23255889/672009 you provided in your question, I believe Retrofit service itself is thread-safe. During execution, the service itself shared nothing writable, and the design of its API is quite similar to FP(function programming) paradigm, if you are familiar with it.