# How to send parallel GET requests with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to create a sample weather app with OpenWeatherMap api. I am having a problem with sending GET requests using Retrofit to retrieve data for weather.
This is my code:

```js
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(END_POINT)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), null)
                .build();
        CurrentApi current = adapter.create(CurrentApi.class);
        current.getByCity("hanoi", "metric", new Callback<CurrentWeather>() {
            @Override
            public void success(CurrentWeather currentWeather, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Hanoi: " + new Gson().toJson(currentWeather));
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        current.getByCityCountry("London,uk", "metric", new Callback<CurrentWeather>() {
            @Override
            public void success(CurrentWeather currentWeather, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "London: " + new Gson().toJson(currentWeather));
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

When I run one of them, it works. But when I make 2 requests with different URL, none of them is called. ('cause I don't see anything logged in Logcat).
How can I deal with this?

Comment: Go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23255889/2276657)

Answer (score 0):

> Methods can be declared for either synchronous or asynchronous execution.
>
> 1. A method with a return type will be executed synchronously.
> 2. Asynchronous execution requires the last parameter of the method be a Callback.

--FROM the [Official site](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my mistake :D I forgot I have filtered the results so I can't find the log :D My code still works!