# How to limit parallel requests with Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, retrofit2

My goal is to limit the number of parallel executing request by throwing an exception.

For example, I want only one executing request:

```
someApi.getUser(
    result -> print("ok: " + result), exception -> print("error: " + exception)
); // this request will be executed in 5 seconds

someApi.getServerInfo(
    result -> print("ok: " + result), exception -> print("error: " + exception)
); // there I want to catch exception like ExecutorIsBusy
```

How can I implement it with Retrofit 2.0?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question but it may point you in the right direction. I am thinking of two possibilities here. First, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255523/parallel-http-requests-with-retrofit/23255889. It's for Retrofit 1 & not 2 so I am not sure it can't be applied. Second, you could turn the the call into an observable & use a conditional operator to keep other subscriptions from occurring until the current one is finished.

Comment: Rate limit is best set on server side... using user id or ip address based on your framework that you use like laravel, django, express etc.  This way performance will not be compromized and also only those users who are mischevious will face a rate limit

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that throwing an `Exception` is the best way to do it, but I don't know your use case so I will not discuss this point :)

Anyway, the comment of @Daniel actually points to a pretty good direction. If you're using `retrofit` with `OkHttp`, it's the `OkHttpClient` that will handle the "concurrent requests" stuff. Reading the docs, you could see that OkHttp uses a `Dispatcher` to handle parallel asynchronous requests ([Dispatcher docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html)).

So two interesting points are :

1. Method `setMaxRequests(int maxRequests)` : defines the maximum concurrent requests
2. Method `executed(RealCall call)` : actually executes a requests

I think you could do this to achieve your goal :

1. Create a custom `Dispatcher` class
2. Overrides the `executed(RealCall call)` method throwing an exception if the number of currents request is superior to `maxRequests`
3. Use the custom `Dispatcher` in the `OkHttpClient` you're using with `retrofit`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your solution.

Comment: `> I am not sure that throwing an Exception is the best way to do it;` I need only one request executing at the same time. And I need to reject any request before the current was executed. What can be more suitable than throwing Exception? @Daniel suggests to use Observable, but I can't imagine how to do it as I just started to use reactive programming.

Comment: I don't know either ;) If could be better to not try your request if you should not do it instead of "trying and failing" ;)

Comment: If you were to use `RxJava`, you could set a `boolean` value to `true` while an `observable` is running & once that `observable` is finished you could set the flag back to `false` in `onCompleted()`. Then any time you run an `observable` and the flag has already been set to `true`, you don't make the call.

Comment: I just tried that approach and it worked in my sample project so it may work for you. Let me know if I can help any further.

Answer (score 1):

Using RxJava & taking the approach in the above comments, here is an example:

Assume that these operations are attached to buttons.

```
public void runObservable1(View view) {
    if (!taskRunning){
        try{
            taskRunning = true;
            subsonicService.runTask1()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .compose(this.<Result>bindUntilEvent(ActivityEvent.DESTROY))
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            taskRunning = false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Result result) {
                            //your logic here
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task is running you must wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

public void runObservable2(View view) {

    if (!taskRunning){
        try{
            taskRunning = true;
            subsonicService.runTask2()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .compose(this.<Result>bindUntilEvent(ActivityEvent.DESTROY))
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            taskRunning = false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Result result) {
                            //Logic here
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task is running you must wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am also not an expert at RxJava so there may be an operator that makes this easier.